# How to keep comments on their own line with algorithmicx?

Tags: algorithmicx

I'm trying to add comments on their own line. the default behaviour of `\Comment{}` is to place the comment on the same line as a `\State`. My current hack is to just do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\captionsetup\[algorithm\]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Init}
\begin{algorithmic}\[1\]
  \State // Here is a comment the way I want it.
  \State $x \gets y$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}]
```

Desired output:

[image: output]

Is there a proper way to do this? What about making the comment italicized so that it's a little less intrusive?

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and a image of the desired result.

Comment: OK. I expanded the code and added an image.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed some errors in the code:

- replaced the 2 occurrences of `\[...\]` with `[...]`
- deleted the last character `]`

I added the `\textit` command to get the comment italicized.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Init}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State // \textit{Here is a comment the way I want it.}
            \State $x \gets y$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also define a command for your comment type (`\CommentLine`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=empty}

\newcommand{\CommentLine}[1]{
    \State // \textit{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Init}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \CommentLine{Here is a comment the way I want it.}
            \State $x \gets y$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the way [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)'s `\Comment` works using

```
\algrenewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{// {\itshape #1}}
```

The default behaviour is to insert `\hfill \(\triangleright\)`, which puts the comment flush with the right margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=empty}

\algrenewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{// {\itshape #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Init}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State // Here is a comment the way I want it.
    \State $x \gets y$
    \State \Comment{Here is a comment the way I want it.}
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```