# algorithmicx \comment command

Tags: algorithms, comments, algorithmicx

```
\documentclass{tudelft-report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{cICA}\label{cICA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{cICA}{}\Comment{The procedure of cICA}
\State \textbf{Initialization} $b$\Comment{Initialize the parameters}
\begin{align*}
    \mu& = 1      \quad \lambda  = 1\\
    \gamma& = 1   \quad \eta  = 1\\
    threshold& = 0.00001 \quad flag =1\\
\end{align*}
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{stop the loop when the changed value of weighted 
vector is larger than threshold}
\State $\mu_{t} = max\{0,\mu_{t-1}+\gamma g(w_{t-1})\}$
\State $\lambda_{t} = \lambda_{t-1}+\gamma h(w_{t-1})$
\State $\Gamma_{1} = \overline{\rho}E\{zG'_{y}(y)\} - \frac{1}{2}\mu E\{zg'_{y}(y)\}-\lambda E\{zy\}$
\State $\Gamma_{2} = \overline{\rho}E\{G"_{y^{2}}(y)\} - \frac{1}{2}\mu E\{g"_{y^{2}}(y)\}-\lambda$
\If{$norm(w_{k} - w_{k-1}) < threshold$ }
 \State flag = 0;
\Else
\State flag = 1;
\EndIf
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $w$\Comment{The optimal weight vector $w$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

When I was using the comment command in algorithmicx, there is always a bank
square at the beginning of the text. Could anaynoe help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the way [algorithmicx](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)'s `\Comment` works using

```
\algrenewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{\hfill #1}
```

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378627/how-to-keep-comments-on-their-own-line-with-algorithmicx#389930), the default behavior of `\Comment` is to insert `\hfill \(\triangleright\)`. The above redefines it to not render a symbol. You can alternatively use any other symbol.

When replacing the `documentclass{tudeflt-report}` with another documentclass, e.g. `\documentclass{article}`, the triangle is correctly rendered (instead of the box), so this might be an issue with the used documentclass.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmicx,algpseudocode}

\algrenewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{\hfill #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{cICA}\label{cICA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{cICA}{}\Comment{The procedure of cICA}
\State \textbf{Initialization} $b$  \Comment{Initialize the parameters}
\begin{align*}
    \mu& = 1      \quad \lambda  = 1\\
    \gamma& = 1   \quad \eta  = 1\\
    threshold& = 0.00001 \quad flag =1\\
\end{align*}
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{stop the loop when the changed value of weighted 
vector is larger than threshold}
\State $\mu_{t} = max\{0,\mu_{t-1}+\gamma g(w_{t-1})\}$
\State $\lambda_{t} = \lambda_{t-1}+\gamma h(w_{t-1})$
\State $\Gamma_{1} = \overline{\rho}E\{zG'_{y}(y)\} - \frac{1}{2}\mu E\{zg'_{y}(y)\}-\lambda E\{zy\}$
\State $\Gamma_{2} = \overline{\rho}E\{G"_{y^{2}}(y)\} - \frac{1}{2}\mu E\{g"_{y^{2}}(y)\}-\lambda$
\If{$norm(w_{k} - w_{k-1}) < threshold$ }
 \State flag = 0;
\Else
\State flag = 1;
\EndIf
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $w$\Comment{The optimal weight vector $w$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered LaTeX]

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Would you like to mark the answer as accepted?